# Android Null pointer exception onCreate

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, oncreate

So I am just learning to write android apps, nothing specific yet but mainly toying around to see how they work. I tried to do something with tabs in the action bar, based off a tutorial I found, but I get a null pointer exception thrown before the app even launches.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for(String tab_names : tabs)
    {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_names).setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0,float arg1,int arg2)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_fragment, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

there are 2 other classes of the onCreateView with different layouts but are exactly the same otherwise. Here are the xml, the first is the main and the next for the fragment:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ff8400">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the thrown exception. I also can't seem to get logcat to export to a log file so I will try to get that on here as well.

**Logcat**

```
 02-28 01:36:42.431: I/Process(1629): Sending signal. PID: 1629 SIG: 9

   02-28 01:37:27.401: D/AndroidRuntime(1668): Shutting down VM

   02-28 01:37:27.401: W/dalvikvm(1668): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a1fb90)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668): Process: com.example.tolerablenausea, PID: 1668

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tolerablenausea/com.example.tolerablenausea.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:343)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at com.example.tolerablenausea.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:29)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)

   02-28 01:37:27.471: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: show the logcat please

Comment: `for(String tab_names : tabs)`

Where does `tabs` come from?

Comment: At which line you are getting null pointer exception? Post line.

Comment: Unsure of the line since logcat doesn't seem to tell me what is going on. The tabs comes from a private string array initialized as part of the class

Comment: check you version it should be >= 11

Comment: You are learning, but you need to post logcat.  It will point to the line in code.

Answer (score 1):

Where the for each loop has been used, can't see the "tabs" being initialized. If it is null and there is no "String" in it.

Check:
If your android:minSdkVersion is set to 8 (API-8), it does not provide getActionBar() (only since API-11).

If lint warnings are suppressed, you won't get a compile time error for that.

Try http://actionbarsherlock.com/ - backward compatibility helps.

If you want to check, 
see if this works:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: My minSdkVersion is 14 at the moment, with a targetSdk of 19

Comment: @user3363625 pls post the logcat to trace error precisely

Answer (score 0):

I think getActionbar() method return null value, you can follow the link provided below.

[NullPointException with getActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501252/nullpointexception-with-getactionbar),

[getActionBar() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null)

It may help you.
Mark as answer if it is helpful to you.