# android and emulator remove actionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

hello i have to remove actionBar into an activity, this is my style:

```
<style name="AppTemaGiornoFullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>        
</style>
```

this work very well into android 4x, but into an 2x emulator actionBar is always visible.. why?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646169/actionbar-pre-honeycomb

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it programatically from the Activity itself using this line of code in your 
`OnCreate` method after `setContentView` line

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

If you are using tabs activity, use this:

```
getParent().getActionBar().hide();
```

This is a similar question .. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914791/android-3-0-action-bar-dont-want-to-go)

---

If you are asking about hiding the `TitleBar` programatically..Add the following lines on your `onCreate` before `setContentView` line

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This is a similar question .. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

Comment: this not work on pre Honeycomb, please see my link on comment of question

Comment: Try to do it from the Mainfest in the Activity declaration by adding this line to your activity `<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />`

Comment: i don't ask this question, but even add that this not work because Android pre-Honeycomb doesn't have an ActionBar

Comment: but if actionbar not exist into Android 2x why i can see it into emulator?

Comment: Are you sure @fabio, that you are talking about the ActionBar :D !!

Comment: only on android 2x emulator i see a menu bar on top :(

Comment: Can you post an image for it? @fabio

Comment: @fabio, Check my updated answer ... Add the final line. I hope it works

Comment: i add this this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) but i can see actionbar.. emulator problem?

Comment: May be you have to check the links that I provided in the Answer, and I if you find any of my answers useful directly or indirectly, please vote it up. Thnx in advance @fabio