# How to disable popups on clicking clock in Android Honeycomb?

Tags: android

I have an android application. I have made application fullscreen but as status bar remains on screen, if the user clicks on the clock and hits Settings, my application goes to the background.

How can i disable this?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-an)

So the answer is you can't disable it (on non-rooted devices).
but you can hide icons on it

try this to do it:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```