# make a own System Bar

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

i want to replace the original systemUI.apk form a android 3.x System with a own one. Did anyone try this before or maybe got a openSource project for this

for example the systemUI.apk is the menuBar, i want a own with only back, home and maybe the time, nothing else

THX

Comment: The UOT kitchen manages it: http://uot.dakra.lt/kitchen/ so it must be possible. But you would be much better off asking that on http://forum.xda-developers.com because XDA is focused around system modifications. Of course the device would need to be rooted, though. And you would use Runtime.exec(...) to run linux commands to do the copying. Regardless, xda is really the best place to ask.

Comment: thx i will look there and report it to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution for my problem, maybe this can help other programmers too.
first of all, I hide the SystemBar with this Answer:

[Is there a way to hide the system bar in Android 3.0? It's an internal device and I'm managing navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-an)

Then i create my own home button Service with allways show a home icon on the left side of the top. The Service got a onTouchEvent, looks like this

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getRawY() < 50 && event.getRawX() < 50)
    {
        Context context = getContext();
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(startMain);
    }
    return true;
}
```

i hope this can help people out, if not ask me a question :-) i will try to help you

Comment: brilliant ! Please write more about your app.