# android 4.0 FullScreen

Tags: android, debugging, android-fragments, fullscreen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i want make Fullscreen in android 4.0, i use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`
the action bar is disappear, but the status bar isn't appear

i use

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

before `"setContentView()"`

OK, FullScreen!!  however, when the dialog or popupwindow show, the status bar appear again,
i read the source code and find the word :

- There is a limitation: because navigation controls are so important,
  the least user interaction will cause them to reappear immediately.

can i make fullscreen anytime? help me!

Answer (score 1):

> There is a limitation: because navigation controls are so important, the least user * interaction will cause them to reappear immediately.

In other words, Android is telling you that the limitation exists because it would be a bad idea to prevent the user from accessing the navigation controls. Doing so would surely disrupt the user experience and would probably piss off a lot of users. That said, unless you have a *very* good reason for doing so, you should leave it the way it is.

Comment: thanks, i find a way to make fullscreen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988, rename two files in /system/app