# android How to set Hidden this bar (in tablet Android 4.0.3)

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my app to Fullscreen (with no any bar) how I can coding to set it. (Android version 4.0.3)
Thx very Much [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hide that bar. [On Honeycomb(3.0) there was a bug](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=306) that would allow it to be hidden(on a rooted device), but it was fixed in ICS(4.0). ([Note: see this answer for more techniques that worked on 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956361/507810))As of now there is no way to do it on 4.0. Unfortunately, because devices no longer have physical buttons the navigation buttons (home and back) have to be put onto the screen. Because that bar contains the navigation buttons if you were to hide it, it would be possible to "lock" the user out of the device by not allowing them to leave your application(at least until they rebooted into safe mode).

So if you want to do that you'll have to make your own custom version of the OS to allow for it.