# How to hide android status bar just for my application on Android Tabs2 fro Android version4.0.3?

Tags: android, statusbar

Can any one please tell me any way to hide status bar completely just for my application on all activities. My application only runs on android tabs with 4.0.3 Android. I actually want to remove the back, home and all the other click listeners on the status bar or just completely hide it. The requirement behind this is that if once my application starts on a tab it stays on until user switches off the device device and there should not be any exit point. I will be grateful for your humble response. I have added android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" manifest.xml.Still not able to disable the status bar. My activity class is given below

```
package com.plugin.myapp;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap  {
     private static MainActivity instance;

    // private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        super.init(); 

        //getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/tdc_tutorial.html");

    }
 // handler for the background updating
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        System.out.println("onConfigurationChanged");
    }
  @Override
    public void init() {
    super.init((CordovaWebView) new WebView(this), new GWTCordovaWebViewClient(this), new CordovaChromeClient(this));
    }

   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onBackPressed();
    } 

   /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.cordova.DroidGap#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)
     */

}
```

and my manifest.xml is given below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.plugin.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<supports-screens     
      android:largeScreens="true"    
      android:normalScreens="true"    
      android:smallScreens="true"  
      android:xlargeScreens="true"  
      android:resizeable="true"    
      android:anyDensity="true"

      /> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Android Test"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" > 


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"            
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to hide the system bar in Android 3.0? It's an internal device and I'm managing navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-an)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GMD HideBar for ICS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1769761).
I used it on my 4.0.3 tablet and it works very good! if you use dex2jar to get jar from apk file, I could import jar file in your buildpath and use function `SystemUI.hidebar` to hide or `SystemUI.showbar` to show :)

Answer (score 0):

For devices without hardware key, unless you "Root" device, there's no way to completely hide the bar. You can, however, put it in "low profile" mode using [setSystemUIVisiblity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

By default, you **shouldn`t** remove the statusbar, because it is a service from the Android UI. Then Google let you hide it, however if the user swipes it up, it will come back.

But, yes **it is possible to do** if you have root access on the device.

This code can hide and show the StatusBar by killing it`s proccess and calling it back again.

```
package com.example.statusbar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String commandToExecute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        commandToExecute = "/system/xbin/su";
        executeShellCommand(commandToExecute);

        Button btHideStatusBar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHide);
        Button btShowStatusBar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShow);


        btHideStatusBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                commandToExecute = "/system/xbin/su -c /system/bin/service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui";
                executeShellCommand(commandToExecute);

            }
        });

    btShowStatusBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            commandToExecute = "/system/xbin/su -c /system/bin/am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService";
            executeShellCommand(commandToExecute);

        }
    });

    }

    private boolean executeShellCommand(String command) {
        try {

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;

        }
    }


}
```