# Android how to hide the default home , time showing bar in android

Tags: android

Hi any one knows how to hide the default home, back time showing system bar by android?

Comment: you mean notification bar ?

Comment: The bar which has the home icon back icon signal strength time and shows the battery level

Comment: you want to hide for your an activity  ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you want to make it fullscreen, therefore you can use this:

You can hide the default system bar by using the following code for an activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Here an example of a splash screen:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You should put it in every activity that must be fullscreen.
Using this line of code in the `<application>` tag is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.0 and above you can use [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

You however, seem to be talking about Android 3.0, as that is the one in which the battery level etc. is usually shown alongside navigation. It is not possible to hide this bar using the Android SDK, but there are a few alternative methods, as outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5109988/1069068) question.

Comment: @Kalanamith no this will not work on Android 3.0, as `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` was introduced only in Android 4.0. However, the question I linked you to has some unofficial methods of doing what you want.

Comment: Yep um going through them one by one . Thank you.