# How to hide navigation bar in Android App Code

Tags: android, navigation, hide, tablet, adk

I added this code to my app ;

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

But The code forces me to add  "SuppressLint NewApi to MainActivity".Also there is an error about "View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN".Code says "CHANGE TO...." so what I must do I don't know.

Please help me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Comment: I looked for this training but it didn't help.

Comment: what is your target Api?

Comment: I'm using 4.0.4 tablet

Answer (score 6):

Here is **simple code to hide Navigation bar** in Activity. It is working.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Answer (score 2):

For API level 19:

In addition to setting the fullscreen flag, I also had to add the following to hide the soft keys:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

You can also set the sticky immersion as described here:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 0):

The code that you use is for API level 14 or higher, like described in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

The `SuppressLint NewApi to MainActivity` happens because probably your target API level (or your  minTarget) is less than 14.

And as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-an) says, you can't hide the navigation bar

EDIT:

Set your `android:minSdkVersion="14"`
There's a restriction: you if are using a device that don't have the traditional hardware keys (back,Home,Menu) you can't hide the navigation bar.

Comment: I'm new in android.How can I find out my Api Level.I only know that my device version is 4.0.4

Comment: Open your `AndroidManifest.xml` an see the lines about TargetVersion into `<uses-sdk>` tag.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: I'm updating my answer, check it :)

Comment: Ok I did it but I couldnt hide navigation bar :/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it - hides the title and makes it full screen:

```
// requesting to turn the title OFF
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // making it full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I also have this in my AndroidManifest under Application:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

I should note this a minSDK version of 13 and target of 19 (4.4 KitKat)

Answer (score 0):

I am a very novice developer but I discovered that the solution for me was to change the theme and base my theme around any "...NoActionBar" theme. 
I haven't got my head around how to build themes or modify styles yet, but I thing this will probably will be the most efficient way to just get rid of the Action bar on top. 
It does NOT get you into fullscreen mode though. That, I believe you have to do programatically.

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<resources/>
```

Also, if you want to know more about themes, this seems to be a good place for that: https://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/